# Duplicate / Triplicate inline javascript

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

On some pages of my site when inline javascript has been added to page it get added multiple times.

I've looked through my base theme ([Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen)) and my default theme (custom) for anything that may be messing with the drupal_add_js process but I haven't been able to find anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what might be causing this?

Comment: is it adding by ajax? or any ajax process on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the module [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer).  I was using the Default view and should have been using the Full Page Override view.